# Getting no space left on device while running geth --datadir ./datadir console

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain, ubuntu

I am following [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-setting-up-a-private-blockchain-67bbb96cf4f1) tutorial and while running below command.

```
geth --datadir ./datadir console
```

It ran for 15 hours and then returned below error.

> INFO [08-31|09:54:13.343] Imported new state entries
>   count=2111 elapsed=13.073ms  processed=21254438 pending=5885  retry=6 
>   duplicate=393098 unexpected=939711
>
> **CRIT [08-31|09:54:14.764] Failed to store last header's hash       err="write
>   /home/ubuntu/medium-article/datadir/datadir/geth/chaindata/388142.log:
>   no space left on device"**

From the error log its clear this is memory issue but When i check the free memory using `df -h` the output is given below.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  932K  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        55G   52G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             32G     0   32G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Could you please give me some hint where i am going wrong?

Comment: Did you init the node with your genesis before running `geth`?

Comment: Your hard disk is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was,Total memory i had is 128GB but the memory allocated to `/dev/sda1        55G   52G     0 100% /` was 55GB only. so error i was getting.

To solve this i allocated more memory around 100GB to `/dev/sda1`.

For that i had to reinstall OS.